# How to limit memory usage ofPython _ pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Currently am using a panda operation to merge two csv file It take around 4.6 gb RAM i want to limit the RAM usage by 2 gb like java -Xmax and -Xmin

is their any way to do so

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it if you can process your datasets in chunks, otherwise your data will be read completely in memory and then processed

Comment: that also tried but no options to limit with specified memory size

Comment: AFAIK there is no java's `-Xmax` and `-Xmin` equivalents in pandas. How do you want to merge your CSV files - can it be done in chunks - if yes, you can specify a smaller chunks, then pandas won't need that much RAM?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setrlimit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.setrlimit):

```
import resource

rsrc = resource.RLIMIT_DATA
soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(rsrc)
print 'Soft limit starts as  :', soft

resource.setrlimit(rsrc, (1024, hard)) #limit to one kilobyte

soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(rsrc)
print 'Soft limit changed to :', soft
```

**EDIT**: Actually, I'm not sure if `setrlimit` controls the CPU or RAM usage. From the shell, however you could make use of `ulimit`:

```
ulimit -v 128k
python script.py
ulimit -v unlimited
```

**EDIT**: Please note that this is for ***Linux*** systems, and I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's possible on Windows.

Comment: if I remember well there is NO way in windows to control the amount of RAM used

Comment: @Noobie In Windows, that may be true. This is for Linux, I'll update to clarify.

Comment: @Noobie is their any way

Comment: @SubinSoman Post your code and I can help you to reduce the memory usage. I think I know why you have a problem.